# Websockets nginx reverse proxy + Cloudflare

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I'm using `NGINX` to **proxy** a `node.js websockets server` with my subdomain wich is using `CloudFlare` service. 

But when I'm connecting to the websocket server, I have this error `WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxxx.xxxx.tld/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`
*PS: I don't have this error when I'm accessing directly by IP adress:port whitout NGINX reverse proxy.*

Here's my `NGINX` **config file**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxxx.xxxx.tld;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:89;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

For information, I'm using the latest version of `NGINX`.
**What's wrong?** Thanks

Comment: Which CloudFlare plan are you on?

Comment: I'm using the free plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As Nickoplier noted, CloudFlare now supports WebSockets for the free plan too. Be advised that the WebSocket support on the free plan is meant only for low-volume websites (per the [support article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169466-Can-I-use-CloudFlare-with-WebSockets-)).

This does not work because currently CloudFlare only supports WebSockets (in a beta stage) for their business and enterprise customers. See the [support article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169466-Can-I-use-CloudFlare-with-WebSockets-) for more information.

One of the ways to workaround this is to create a new subdomain that is not CloudFlare-enabled. For example ws.xxxx.xxxx.tld, and point your websockets client against that.

Comment: So, if i do that my VPS ip isn't anymore protected?

Comment: That's right. Unfortunately there isn't a way to make WebSockets work with the free plan, at least for the time being.

Comment: This is no longer true as Cloudflare support article has changed.